# One function to populate sql command parameters and run stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my application I have to execute a lot of stored procedures.

I have to write a lot of code for doing this.

For example :

```
_oconn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
_oconn.Open();

SqlCommand ocmd = new SqlCommand();
ocmd.Connection = _oconn;
ocmd.CommandText = "procname";
ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

ocmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 'ABS';
ocmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 123;

var da = new SqlDataAdapter(ocmd);
da.Fill(Obj);

_oconn.Close();
```

I write this code for any procedure with different parameters,

Is there any way to write a function which do it for all my procedures?

Comment: No. Why don't you write it yourself? Any effort at least?

Comment: Create a method for this and you can call that method.

Comment: I have about 30 peocedures with different parameters, I want some generic function to fit all cases.so I wont have to duplicate my code so many times

Comment: This is easy to provide, but please try something on your own, then let the suggestions flow in, that will help you much better

Answer (score 1):

You can't write common one function for different Stored Procedure

But I think the best practice is

```
// this is common function for all datatable
        public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(SqlParameterCollection ObjParams, string StoredProcedureName)
        {
            DataTable Obj = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                SqlConnection _oconn = new SqlConnection();

                _oconn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                _oconn.Open();

                SqlCommand ocmd = new SqlCommand();
                ocmd.Connection = _oconn;
                ocmd.CommandText = StoredProcedureName;
                ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (SqlParameter item in ObjParams)
                    ocmd.Parameters.Add(item);


                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(ocmd);
                da.Fill(Obj);

                _oconn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return Obj;
        }


        // You can write every diffrenet Procedure with different functions 
        public DataTable GetStudents()
        {
            SqlParameterCollection objParams = new SqlParameterCollection();
            objParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", "ABS"));
            objParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", 123));
            var StudentsTable = ExecuteDataTable(objParams, "procname");
        }
```

Comment: Why not create a generic code to create parameter collection using Reflection or XML config, that would make things much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can create as a method, example:

```
private DataSet ExecuteSQLSPDS(string strConnectString, string strSchema, string strStoredProcedureName, ArrayList arlParamName, ArrayList arlParamValue, ref string strErrMsg)
{
    SqlConnection cnResult = new SqlConnection(strConnectString);
    SqlDataAdapter daResult = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        daResult.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
        daResult.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        daResult.SelectCommand.CommandText = strSchema + "." + strStoredProcedureName;
        daResult.SelectCommand.Connection = cnResult;
        daResult.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

        //Form Param
        for (int i = 0; i < arlParamName.Count; i++)
        {
            daResult.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(arlParamName[i].ToString(), arlParamValue[i].ToString()));
        }

        cnResult.Open();
        daResult.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        strErrMsg = e.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cnResult.State.ToString() == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open.ToString())
            cnResult.Close();

        daResult.Dispose();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Then call the method:

```
DataSet ds = ExecuteSQLSPDS(ConnectString, Schema, StoredProcedureName, arlParamName, arlParamValue, ref ErrMsg);
```

Comment: This would still lead to lot of repetitive code, there are ways to refactor to minimize all sort of repetition. Especially for creating collection of Parameters, and still using ArrayList :) start using List<T>